# Send User ID to GA4 via Postman

Tags: google-analytics

We are building an app which cannot benefit from GA4 javascript implementation or dedicated SDKs for mobile development.
So we are trying to build the server requests required to send the tracking data to GA4 (in order to build our own GA4 implementation for our app).
We use Postman to test the requests (sent to https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect).
So far, we have been able to log successfully page view events with a page title.
Below is the body of a successful request – successful regarding events and page names, but not user id.
We also tried to pass the user id in the request's params (rather than the body), but it doesn't work either.
We also tried various versions for the user id key ("user_id" is validated, "uid" fails), and various places (at the body's root, or inside the events' params).

```
{
    "client_id": "(some client id)",
    "user_id": "(some user id)",
    "events":
    [
        {
            "name": "page_view",
            "params":
            {
                "page_title":"Some Page Title",
                "page_location":"Chapter/Sub/Page"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "file_download"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify the reporting identity
Make sure your property uses a reporting identity that includes the User-ID option by doing the following:

1. In Admin, make sure you selected the property you want to edit.
2. In the Property column, click Reporting Identity.
3. Select either By User-ID, Google signals, then device or By User-ID and device.

(c) https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9213390?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
The labels in the french version do not match 100%, but yes: "Par User-ID et appareil" (By User-ID and device) was checked. The other label is: "Par appareil uniquement" (By device only).

Comment: do you see user id set properly in the network calls?

Comment: Yes I do. Besides, I mostly test in Postman, so I'm pretty sure of what is sent.
"Properly set", I'm not quite sure: is it the right name, at the right place?
Or maybe some additional data needs to be sent for GA4 to take this user id into account?

Comment: Also tested via Event Builder https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/event-builder/ and still no user appears in the dashboards.

Comment: try raw export of the data into BQ. Maybe the issue is how you build your dashboards. Or, rather, how google makes them available in GA's interface.